# WebGL: Z-Buffer artifacts on mobile devices

Tags: webgl, shader

I have WebGL context there I'm rendering 3d model of room and furniture. It works ok on PC but gives me strange z-fighting artifacts on mobile devices when i'm inside the room and my near plane close to camera.

[image] [image]

When my clipping planes is far from camera everything works ok even on mobile:

near: 4267.639824060027, far: 11183.900282644734

projectionMatrix = [1.9196896450555059, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.7320508075688774, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2.234082350944259, -1, 0, 0, -13801.866294355888, 0];

But when

zLimits = {near: 30, far: 5960.493230110447}

projectionMatrix = [1.9196896450555059, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.7320508075688774, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.0101172023425247, -1, 0, 0, -60.30351607027574, 0]

The picture become corrupt with z-fighting and triangles of first objects 1000 units far from second object constantly flashing behind the second object triangles

PS: I try to use in my shaders

```
precision highp float
precision highp int
```

and gl.getShaderPrecisionFormat(gl.VERTEX_SHADER, gl.HIGH_FLOAT); results in
WebGLShaderPrecisionFormat {rangeMin: 127, rangeMax: 127, precision: 23}
but it gives me no effect

gl.getParameter(gl.DEPTH_BITS) returns 24;

I have two rendering paths (forward and deferred with DEPTH_COMPONENT32F) and both give me the same artfifacts

PPS: I open similar scene on the same device via app that uses ThreeJS render and it renders scene of similar size without artifacts

PPPS: My vertex & fragment shaders used in forward render

```
export const geometry = new ShaderProgram(
    // vertex shader
    `
    precision highp float;
    uniform mat4 u_transformMatrix;
    uniform mat4 u_modelViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 u_meshMatrix;
    uniform vec3 u_viewDir;

    attribute vec4 a_position;
    attribute vec3 a_normal;
    attribute vec2 a_texcoord;

    varying float v_lighting;
    varying vec3 v_normal;
    varying vec3 v_position;
    varying vec2 v_texcoord;

    void main(void)
    {
        vec4 vertex4 = u_meshMatrix * a_position;
        vec3 normal = (u_meshMatrix * vec4(a_normal, 0.0)).xyz;
        v_normal = (u_modelViewMatrix * vec4(normal, 0.0)).xyz;;
        v_position = (u_modelViewMatrix * vertex4).xyz;
        gl_Position = u_transformMatrix * vertex4;
        v_lighting = min(abs(dot(normal, u_viewDir)) + 0.4, 1.0);
        v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
    }
    `
    ,
    // fragment shader
    `
    precision highp float;
    uniform lowp vec4 color;
    uniform lowp float u_selection;
    uniform sampler2D u_texture;
    uniform lowp float u_opacity;
    uniform lowp vec2 u_textureOffset;
    uniform lowp vec2 u_textureScale;

    varying float v_lighting;
    varying vec2 v_texcoord;
    varying vec3 v_normal;
    varying vec3 v_position;

    void main(void)
    {
        vec3 cur_color = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        float ligtMapVal = v_lighting;
        vec2 texCoord = (v_texcoord + u_textureOffset) * u_textureScale;
        vec3 texColor = texture2D(u_texture, texCoord).xyz;
        //vec3 texColor = vec3(0.4, 0.4, 0.6);
        vec3 selectionColor = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        vec3 color = mix(texColor, selectionColor, u_selection);

        vec3 lightDirection = normalize(vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0));
        float diffuseWeight = max(dot(v_normal, vec3(0, 0, 1)) + 0.2, 0.5);

        vec3 eyeDirection = normalize(-v_position);
        vec3 halfVector = normalize(lightDirection + eyeDirection);
        float uShininess = 25.1;
        float specularWeight = pow(max(dot(v_normal, halfVector), 0.0), uShininess);

        vec3 lightSpecular = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        gl_FragColor = vec4(color * diffuseWeight + specularWeight * lightSpecular, u_opacity);
    }
`
);
```

Comment: Have you tried using a different depth function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/depthFunc

Comment: enjoy the read: https://developer.nvidia.com/content/depth-precision-visualized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main source of problem was that I compile some shaders with mediump precision. They won't even used by rendering paths, but were loading first.
Removing those shaders fixes the problem.

Thanks to [LJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978057/lj) for great doc to optimize it further!